# I have text file in which each row with single word. convert it into line using python

Tags: python

I have a text file with a single word in each row.

I want to convert it into line using Python.

Input: 
`file.txt`

```
word1 in row1
word2 in row2
word3 in row3
word4 in row4
```

Expected Output:
`['word1.Z', 'word2.Z', 'word3.Z', 'word4.Z']`

Comment: So you want to convert it into a line or an array?

Comment: It's unclear what `.Z` has to do with anything. Are you just doing `"<firstwordofline>.Z"`? Your input appears to have more than one word per line :P

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code and indicate which part you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 3):

```
['%s.Z'%s for s in open('myfile.txt').read().split()]
```

or if `myfile.txt` is big:

```
['%s.Z'%s for s in open('myfile.txt').readline().split()]
```

Comment: @joelgoldstick the use of `read` then `split` will avoid any trailing newlines.

Comment: @joelgoldstick this is the result produced by `readline().strip()`->: `['t.Z', 'e.Z', 's.Z', 't.Z']`

Comment: @joelgoldstick my bad, I read `readlines` instead of `readline`. Yes it works with `readline().strip()` and only a single line will be read at once.

Comment: I never thought about your way.  I never use read(), but that's good too for smallish file

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
words = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
```

`readlines()` creates a list where each element is one line of the file, so your `words` list will look like `['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']`.

Comment: this will leave trailing newlines on each list item

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

It will read each line in `test.txt` and save it in a list called 'words'

Then it will loop thought each word, remove `"\n"` and add `".Z"` to them.

```
filename = 'test.txt'
words = open(filename, 'r').readlines()

new_words = []

for word in words:
    new_word = word.strip("\n") + ".Z"
    new_words.append(new_word)

new_words
```

Output:

```
['test.Z','this.Z','text.Z','is.Z','written.Z','in.Z','many.Z','lines.Z']
```